# CoreMIDI MidiReceived Issue

Tags: macos, core-audio, coremidi

I have a thread in my OSX app where I process midi messages stored in a packetList and send them using MIDIReceived(deviceEndpoint, packetList) to a virtual instrument;
As part of my program, I send 16 note-off messages at one time to tell the virtual instrument to stop playing all 16 notes.

There's something strange - if I enable the debug message NSLog(@"Num Packets %d", packetList->numPackets); the code works fine. 
However, if I take NSLog(@"Num Packets %d", packetList->numPackets); away, some notes do not get turned off some times. It's almost as if some messages were skipped over because the thread runs too fast or something.

Could someone explain to me why this is happening? Thanks a lot.

```
- (void) processMIDIThread:(NSObject*)param {

    @autoreleasepool {

MAIN:
        for (;;) {

            if([[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled]) {
                NSLog(@"Thread has been cancelled");
                goto END;
            }
            int pktToTrigger = 0;

            if (midiMode==kKeyboardMode)
                pktToTrigger = 1; // in case note off message is lost
            else
                pktToTrigger = 3;

            // Queue processing starts here
            if (packetList->numPackets >= pktToTrigger) {
                NSLog(@"Num Packets %d", packetList->numPackets);
                OSStatus res = MIDIReceived(deviceEndpoint, packetList);
                if (res)
                    NSLog(@"Problem sending midi packets to virtual device");
//                NSLog(@"Sent %d %d %d" ,(int)packetList->packet->data[0],(int)packetList->packet->data[1],(int)packetList->packet->data[2]);
                [self clearPacketList];
            }
        }
    }
END: [NSThread exit];
     NSLog(@"Exited current thread.");
    ;
}
```

The add packet function

```
- (void) addPacketToPacketList:(Byte*) data ofLength:(int) len {

    if (_midiDeviceMode==kMidiOut) {
        //NSLog(@"length %d", len);
        //NSLog(@"%lld", mach_absolute_time());
        //NSLog(@"Insert %d %d %d" ,(int)data[0],(int)data[1],(int)data[2]);
        currentPacket = MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, PACKETLIST_SIZE, currentPacket, mach_absolute_time(), len, data);

        //packetReady = YES;
        if (!currentPacket) exit(1);
    }


}
```

The calling function from another class

```
-(void) sendAllNoteOffs {

    NSMutableArray* noteZoneArray = [_keyboardView noteZoneArray];

    for (int i=0; i < noteZoneArray.count; i++) {
        NoteZone* nz = [noteZoneArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([nz lastNotePlayed]) {
            NotePacket* note = [NotePacket initWithLeapValue:127 forNote:[nz noteValue] noteOn:NO forChan:_keyboardChannel];
            [_virtualMIDIDevice addPacketToPacketList:note->data ofLength:note->length];
//            [_virtualMIDIDevice addPacketToPacketList:note->data ofLength:note->length];
            [nz setLastNotePlayed:NO];
        }
        [nz setHighlightedOn:NO];
    }
    [_virtualMIDIDevice setAllNotesOffSent:YES];
}
```

**Update :**
Replacing the debug statement with the following seems to work as well.

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.0000001];

But I still don't have a good explanation for it. While not noticeable this means there's a delay in between notes.

Comment: Why are you using a thread? Why don't you just call `MIDIReceived` inside of `sendAllNoteOffs`? This threading approach is completely wrong -- you're polling (wasting a lot of CPU cycles for no benefit) and you aren't using a lock or any other synchronization primitive around the data that's shared between the threads.

Comment: Highly recommend reading Apple's [Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091) and [Threading](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i) guides before going much farther. If you really really need to do the `MIDIReceived` outside of the normal flow of your code, you would be much better off using GCD and `dispatch_async`.

Comment: Hi Kurt, my app sends a lot of midi signals per second. if I put MIDIReceived(deviceEndpoint, packetList); right at the end of the addPacketToPacketList and remove the threading, the app crashes after 2-3 seconds of sending midi signals. I'll take a look at the threading. Thanks.

Comment: What's the backtrace of the crash? I'd focus on understanding and fixing that, first. Adding threads is probably not going to make your problem go away, it's just going to make it harder to reproduce and figure out.

Comment: Hi Kurt, you're right. I don't need the thread actually. My problem of crashing without the threading was that I forgot to clear the packetList. Well, in the process I learnt a whole lot about concurrency :/ Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you been able to fix your "lost" messages?